# How to edit two Google keep notes at the same time?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, google, google-apps, google-keep

How can I use multi window or another gesture to edit to Google keep notes at the same time. I'm on Android 7.0 Nougat. I know I can use multi window, although I would appreciate it if someone could kindly let me know how to being the second window up, but I don't know if you can have the same so, such as keep, in both windows, so as to achieve my goal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't think this is natively possible on Android. However there is an app that you can use, called "Parallel Windows". Unfortunately it no longer seems to be on the Play Store, but you can download it from APKMirror at [this link](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/ijp/parallel-windows-for-nougat/parallel-windows-for-nougat-v1-2_alpha-release/parallel-windows-nougat-v1-2_alpha-android-apk-download/).

To use it you need to enable its Accessibility service and permit it to draw over apps. What it does is create a swipe edge on the right of the screen. Open Keep first, and then edge and click on the bottom icon. Click on the Keep app to mirror it.

I usually tend to disable the accessibility service to disable after use because the swipe edge will otherwise stay permanently; it's up to you to use it how you want.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes along looking for an answer to this like me, I've been opening a browser window for keep, and the app as the second. This works for any app which is website-based.